# Duplicate resources on "cordova build android" command. npm cli and Firebase plugin

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, npm

I'm building a fresh new application from npm with the following plugins and commands

- cordova create prh com.demo.prj hello
- cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm
- cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
  -> put my : google-services.json on root dir
- cordova build android .

This is the error displayed:

> Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
>   [string/google_api_key] C:\Users\user\Cproj\platforms\android\res\values\strings.xml [string/google_api_key] C:\Users\user\Cproj\platforms\android\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
>   [string/google_app_id] C:\Users\user\Cproj\platforms\android\res\values\strings.xml    [string/google_app_id] C:\user\Cproj\platforms\android\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

- I've tried to delete the duplicate values on android\res\values\strings.xml but on each build its coming back and display the same error .
- Is this is currect way to build a cordova based application with fire bash push notification service ?

Thanks .

Comment: Hello, did anyone got the workaround for it?

Comment: No. ended up using only the fcm plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the same problem, in my case, I just removed the Firebase dependencies from the build.gradle files and the build worked perfectly.

[See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51504893/2854878)