# Error executing the build in the app (cordova build android), after adding and configuring "cordova-plugin-firebase"

Tags: android, cordova, firebase

**I created an App using Cordova, then followed the instructions to prepare the App to integrate with the Firebase plugin:**

1. Created the keystore (needed to integrate with Firebase).
2. I created the project of the app in Firebase and I informed the hash
   stored in the keystore.
3. I installed the plugin "cordova-plugin-firebase".
4. Copy the file google-services.json to the root folder of the
   project.

**After following the plugin and firebase documentation, I came across this error:**

> :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot > function without it. 
>     Searched Location: 
>    /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/src/nullnull/debug/google-services.json
>    /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/src/debug/nullnull/google-services.json
>    /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/src/nullnull/google-services.json
>    /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/src/debug/google-services.json
>    /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/src/nullnullDebug/google-services.json
>   /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/google-services.json

**Solution proposed here in SO:**
Copy google-services.json to directory `/platforms/android/app/`, but this generated another error:

> :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
>   > [string/google_app_id] /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml [string/google_app_id] /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
>   >     [string/google_api_key] /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml [string/google_api_key] /myAppCordova2/platforms/android/app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

**PS:**
I tried several fixes proposed here in the SO and none solved my problem, could anyone help me?

Comment: I had a similar error and had to delete some lines from strings.xml, see [this link](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/407) for details

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my case, what solved the problem was to remove the Firebase dependencies from the `build.gradle` files, as I explained in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found a solution to problem:**

Instructions similar to those I followed (and that caused the problem) are available here, although with the versions of the dependencies a bit outdated:

> [https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=pt-br)

What caused the problem in my case was to follow these instructions on the App creation page in Firebase and add the dependencies in the `build.gradle` files of the project and module as can be seen below:

Add in project build.gradle `/project/platforms/android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter ()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        Google()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // Firebase
        classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.0.0'
    }
}
```

And add in module build.gradle `/project/platforms/android/app/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral ()
        jcenter ()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        Google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // Firebase
        classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase: firebase-core: 16.0.0'
    }
}

// Firebase, add at the end of the same file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

**Solution:**

The solution I found was to comment the lines that are preceded by the comment `// Firebase`:

File: `/project/platforms/android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter ()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        Google()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // Firebase
        // classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.0.0'
    }
}
```

File: `/project/platforms/android/app/build.gradle`:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral ()
            jcenter ()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
            Google()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

            // Firebase
            //classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.0.0'
            //classpath 'com.google.firebase: firebase-core: 16.0.0'
        }
    }

// Firebase, add at the end of the same file
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

After these steps, everything worked fine and I was able to run `$ cordova build android` without problems.

---

**Suggestion:**
If any other errors occur, try removing the plugins and platform, then re-create them:

```
$ cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase
$ cordova platform rm android

$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
$ cordova platform add android
```